# Googletest does not run test fixture

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I am trying to use googletest for unit testing in C++. I have defined a text fixture in `ClusteringTest.h`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace EnsembleClustering {

class ClusteringTest: public ::testing::Test {

    ClusteringTest() {};

    virtual ~ClusteringTest() {};

    virtual void SetUp() {

    };

    virtual void TearDown() {

    };

};

TEST_F(ClusteringTest, doesGTestWork) {
    EXPECT_EQ(42, 42);
}


} /* namespace EnsembleClustering */
```

In my main function, I call:

```
 ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
 return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

The result is:

```
running EnsembleClustering
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

Why is my test not run?

Comment: Use CCPUnit http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/

Comment: No. I started using CppUnit and after a while it crashed on me because of a bug in the library. That's why I am switching to GTest.

Comment: Then use a debugger - gbx or dbx

Comment: You can link the gtest_main.lib, then the gtest library will execute all tests automatically without explicit main entry point.

Comment: How are you compiling? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: @exagi: simply linking `gtest_main` does not execute the test.
I use Eclipse.

Comment: What about a single code snippet that we can take, compile and link the same way you do to test and see ourselves?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - guess no luck here

Comment: @PlasmaHH Here's a simple example which you can compile yourself: https://gist.github.com/4267814 This works for me, too. I just don't see why the test fixture above does not get discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include your header, ClusteringTest.h, into a .cpp file somewhere to make it concrete, and to create a compilation unit.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I tried to put everything in a header file without having an implementation source file or including it anywhere.

Comment: Peter:  I'm having the same problem but I don't understand your answer, because I have set up the test fixture in a cpp file (without a header).  I can ask another question but someone will consider it a duplicate.  Can you take a look at my file here:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tC1ewFw3KlTnJ1MjdZMFFhdjA&authuser=0

Comment: @cls : I'm having the same problem but I don't understand this answer, because I have set up the test fixture in a cpp file (without a header). I can ask another question but someone will consider it a duplicate. Can you take a look at my file here:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tC1ewFw3KlTnJ1MjdZMFFhdjA&authuser=0

Comment: @Lucy ask a new question, you'll get more people to help than just me.